# Como corrigir o erro: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao tentar testar minha função:

> SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"

A função é esta:

```
function onGetInstanceName(e, args) {
    rootScope.instance_name = _storage.local.get("instance_name") || _storage[storage].get("instance_name");
    rootScope.instanceSelected = JSON.parse(_storage.local.get("instanceSelected")) || JSON.parse(_storage[storage].get("instanceSelected"));
    // console.log(rootScope.instanceSelected);
    log("info", rootScope.instance_name);
    if (null === rootScope.instance_name || '' === rootScope.instance_name) {
        log("info", $state.$current.name, ' ', $state.$current.url);
    }
    rootScope.instance_id = parseInt(_storage[storage].get('instance_id')) || rootScope.instance_id;
    rootScope.$broadcast('getOperatorLogged', null);
}
```

E o teste esta sendo feito da seguinte maneira:

```
it('testing if the onDisplaySelectionInstance function', function(){        
    srv.onDisplaySelectionInstance();
    rootScope.$emit('displaySelectionInstance', null);   
});
```

O que tenho que fazer para corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Tente dar `console.log` em `_storage.local.get("instanceSelected")` e `_storage[storage].get("instanceSelected")`, provavel que algum deles estejam indefinidos.

Comment: Antes do JSON.parse, tente verificar o que esta chegando, para ver se o json esta completo.

Comment: @LucasCosta após ter dado console.log obtive que: _storage.local.get("instanceSelected") é null e _storage[storage].get("instanceSelected") é undefined. O que preciso fazer agora?

Comment: Não precisa duplicar os comentários Alexia, nós veremos. Você precisa nos dizer ou descobrir o eles são e porque estão nulos.

Comment: @LucasCosta tem alguma maneira que eu possa definir isso?

Comment: Pra ser honesto, qual a origem deles? No caso o que é `_storage`, etc..